# VHDL counter skipping numbers (FPGA button trigger)

Tags: vhdl, fpga, edge-detection

I am trying to trigger on a rising pulse in VHDL. However, when my code runs on an FPGA, it skips numbers. Here is the code.

```
 signal DACcntr   :     std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
     signal r0_input  :     std_logic; --used in Rising Edge detector
     signal r1_input  :     std_logic; --used in Rising Edge detector

     CLK   : in std_logic;
     KEY : in std_logic;

DAC_Out_Rising_Edge: process(CLK)
    begin 
    if (rising_edge(CLK)) then
        r0_input <= KEY;  -- These two need two rising edges 
        r1_input <= r0_input; -- These two need two rising edges
        if (not r1_input and r0_input)= '1' then 
            DACcntr <= DACcntr + 1;
        end if;
```

I got this code from the web with a little modification. My understanding is the rising edge of KEY will keep (not r1_input and r0_input) = '1' for one clock cycle. During the clock cycle, DACcntr increments. I can see DACcntr through a string of LEDs. However, when I press the KEY button, it skips several numbers. Please help me with my code logic.

Comment: See the answer to  [edge detection of signal in vhdl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33072002/edge-detection-of-signal-in-vhdl/33088498#33088498) for why it can happen (key bounce) and [Debounce Logic Circuit (with VHDL example)](https://eewiki.net/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=4980758) and [Debounce Logic Circuit (with VHDL example)](https://eewiki.net/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=4980758) for a debouncer example. Without knowing your clock rate and having a [mcve], the issue and a fix can't be demonstrated.

Comment: It was late for me last night when I tried the code. I suspected it could be bounce. I just re-wrote the code to generate a signal at 1 Hz to be the new input "KEY" for this code. The low bit LED looks to evenly flash as 1 Hz. In the board schematics, there is a Schmitt trigger in the circuit. At 3.3v, that would be a lot of bounce to cross the schmitt levels whatever they are. My clock is 50 MHz. If my code is correct, is there a simple modification I can do to catch the first rising edge and ignore say the next 10 clock cycles?

Comment: "that would be a lot of bounce to cross the schmitt levels" Schmitt triggers help if you have analogue signals with low amplitude. Not against key bouncing which gives signals rapidly changing between 0 and 3V3. You can try to add an RC to the input. Your Schmitt input will help with that.

Comment: Aside from what others said, notice that your `if` condition will only be evaluated in the next clock cycle. As you know `r1_input` and `r0_input` values are only updated at the end of your process, thus the `if` condition will only be true in the next clock cycle. Consider moving your increment condition outside the process to avoid this "performance delay".