# vhdl code bug counter with debouncing of push button

Tags: vhdl, fpga, vivado

I need to implement a counter to 100 that increases its count every push button press. It has a debouncing circuit using a rising edge detector.

I got mistakes in the simulation: the counter increases without syncing the push press button. I’m not sure where is the problem, please help me.

The CLK is 100 MHz.

Here is the code:

```
library IEEE;

use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.numeric_std.all;
use IEEE.std_logic_unsigned.all;

entity counter is
    Port ( clk : in STD_LOGIC;
    reset : in STD_LOGIC;
    button : in STD_LOGIC;
    count : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (6 downto 0));
end counter;

architecture Behavioral of counter is
    signal debounced_button : std_logic;
    signal prev_debounced_button : std_logic := '0';
    signal counter_value : unsigned(6 downto 0) := (others => '0');
    begin
    -- Debounce the button signal using a rising edge detector
    process (clk)
    begin
        if rising_edge(clk) then
            if button = '1' and prev_debounced_button = '0' then
                debounced_button <= '1';
            else
                debounced_button <= '0';
            end if;
        
            prev_debounced_button <= debounced_button;
        end if;
    end process;

    -- Count up when the button is pressed
    process (clk, reset)
    begin
        if reset = '1' then
            counter_value <= (others => '0');
        elsif rising_edge(clk) then
            if debounced_button = '1' then
                if counter_value = 100 then
                    counter_value <= (others => '0');
                else
                    counter_value <= counter_value + 1;
                end if;
            end if;
        end if;
    end process;

    -- Convert the counter value to a std_logic_vector for output
    count <= std_logic_vector(counter_value);

end Behavioral;

--test bench:

library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.numeric_std.all;

entity counter_tb is
end counter_tb;

architecture Behavioral of counter_tb is
component counter
Port ( clk    :  in STD_LOGIC;
       reset  :  in STD_LOGIC;
       button :  in STD_LOGIC;
       count  : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (6 downto 0));
end component;

signal clk : std_logic := '0';
signal reset : std_logic := '0';
signal button : std_logic := '0';
signal count : std_logic_vector(6 downto 0);

-- Stimulus process to generate clock and input signals
begin
    uut: counter port map (
        clk => clk,
        reset => reset,
        button => button,
        count => count
    );

    clk_gen: process
    begin
        clk <= '0';
        wait for 5 ns;
        clk <= '1';
        wait for 5 ns;
    end process clk_gen;

    stim_proc: process
    begin
        -- hold reset state for 100 ns.
        reset <= '1';
        wait for 20 ns;
        reset <= '0';
        wait;
    end process;

    process    
    begin
        button <= '0';
        wait for 40ns;
        button <='1';
        wait for 40ns;
        button <= '0';
        wait for 40ns;
        button <='1';
        wait for 40ns;
        button <= '0';
        wait for 40ns;
        button <='1';
        wait for 40ns;
    end process;

end Behavioral;
```

I think I have problem in the test bench, I'm not sure.

Here is the simulation:

[image: the simulation.]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code

Comment: As it is `debounced_button` that drives the counter increment why don't you add it to your waveforms? It would help you better understand what's going on. And while you're at it, also add `prev_debounced_button` and `counter_value`. Your problem is just basic debugging. I suggest that you learn how to debug, it is a very useful skill.

Comment: Remove superfluous double line spacing.  Fix indentation. ". ...At least one separator is required between an identifier or an abstract literal and an adjacent identifier or abstract literal." (code portability).  *I’m not sure where in the problem* isn't a clear problem statement. 1 us isn't an adequate time to catch a button bounce even if the debounce worked. [Your testbench could model real bounces](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33088498).

Comment: See [Debounce Logic Circuit (VHDL)](https://forum.digikey.com/t/debounce-logic-circuit-vhdl/12573) on Digi-Key's TechForum for working debounce code and a treatise on counter size.

Answer (score 0):

You have two processes. The second process is a simple counter with an asynchronous reset -- no issues here. But let's look at the first.

```
    process(clk)
    begin
        if rising_edge(clk) then
            if button = '1' and prev_debounced_button = '0' then
                debounced_button <= '1';
            else
                debounced_button <= '0';
            end if;
        
            prev_debounced_button <= debounced_button;
        end if;
    end process;
```

You have three signals, which I'll call `button`, `debounced` and `prev`. Note that they're *signals*, declared at the architecture level, and not *variables* within the process. Signals and variables are fundamentally different, as we'll see.

You also declare in the process' sensitivity list that it is sensitive only to `clk`. The simulator will only run this process whenever `clk` changes.

On the first rising edge of the clock, this process checks if the button is pressed, and if `prev` is zero. If so, it sets `debounced` to 1, else, it's set to 0. But `debounced` is a signal, which in this process is both being *set* and *used*. In a real system, this is called a *race condition*, and it's indeterminate which operation happens first. Your simulator handles this by always using the value of the signal in the previous time step. At time *t-1*, `debounced` was 0, so any statement that uses `debounced` at time *t* will use 0. Even if `debounced` is being changed to 1.

In other words, you have `button` high, `debounced` was just set high, and `prev` stays low.

On the second rising edge of the clock, it's likely `button`is still high as button presses last on the order of a million clock cycles. Since `prev` is still 0, `debounced` stays at 1, but this time the last `debounced` was 1 so `prev` is now set to 1.

Third rising edge, `debounced` goes to 0, since `prev` is now 1. `prev` stays 1.

Fourth rising edge, `prev` is still reading as 1, so `debounced` stays 0. `prev` now reads the old `debounced` and is now set to zero.

Fifth rising edge, `prev` reads as zero, so `debounced` goes to 1. But `prev` stays at 0 until the next tick.

This pattern continues as long as `button` is pressed. Once `button` goes to 0, then `debounced` is guaranteed to go to 0 on the next rising edge, and `prev` will go to 0 on the following tick.

In other words, `debounced` goes 1-1-0-0-1-1-0-0... oscillating at half the clock frequency for as long as the button is pressed.  This isn't a debouncer. It's just using a button to turn on an oscillator. Any time `button` is 1, `debounced_button`  will toggle; any time `button` is 0, `debounced` stays 0.

It's worth noting at this time that the second process uses `debounced_button`.

---

On to the simulation. Your system starts with `previous` at 0. At 40 ns, `button` goes high. What happens?

Nothing, at first -- you need a rising edge, which comes at 45 ns. **Simultaneously**, two processes run. The debouncer sees a button press, and sets `debounced` to 1. The counter *uses the old value* of `debounced`, and does nothing. `prev` *uses the old value* of `debounced`, and stays 0.

Next rising edge (55 ns), `button` is still high and `prev` is still low, so `debounced` stays at '1'. `prev` now goes to 1. Since `debounced` was high, the counter uses the old value, and now it increments.

65 ns: `prev` reads as 1, so `debounced` goes low. But since it was high a moment ago, the count increments again.

75 ns: `debounced` reads low, the counter doesn't increment.

85-115 ns: `button` is low, so `debounced` stays low, and the counter doesn't increment.

125 ns: `button` is high, so `debounced` goes high, but as should be obvious by now, the count won't increment.

Finally, note `counter_value` and `count`: `count` isn't being set inside a process with a sensitivity list, so it just changes immediately after `counter_value`, i.e. on the next simulator time step. **Your processes run only when the simulator detects a change in a signal on its sensitivity list, and runs using a "snapshot" of the state of the signals at the start of the process.** If you were using variables instead of signals, those are changed immediately and used identically to how sequential logic works in a standard programming language like C.

In reality, if you synthesize this design, you'll find that the behaviour is indeterminate. Your specific FPGA chip and the results of place and route will determine whether a signal is read before or after it's written.

When you have logic that *changes* a value and *consumes* it at the same time, the behaviour is indeterminate. You don't know which will happen first. I recommend having all outputs change on one clock edge (e.g. rising), and latch your inputs on the other clock edge (e.g. falling), to ensure that your inputs are stable before you try to use them.

---

Finally, debugging's a lot easier if you look at the internal signals. I simulated your code for 200 ns and got this:

[image]

Here, you can see exactly what's happening with `prev` and `debounced`, and immediately understand that there's a one-clock delay in the signal propagation.

Also, you can immediately see that your simulation's different from mine. It helps if you actually run the code you post here.